# Unity launcher & Transmission have strange behaviour 

Tags: unity, transmission

[image: Unity Launcher]

My Unity Launcher Behaves weirdly
as you can see I get two Transmission icons in the launcher

Also at times Transmission messes up...

EG: If I check the indicator menu of transmission, there is a tick mark on 'Show Transmission' and yet I cannot see the transmission window anywhere.

This weird launcher behaviour messes my XBMC position too... new apps icons load above XBMC and not below it ...

Answer (score 0):

Unlock both icons while they are showing. Then search for Transmission in the Dash and *drag* the icon on the Launcher.

Comment: did that twice and thrice

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to cause a two icon issue by copying any .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications renaming it and dragging the .desktop launcher to the launch bar. Apparently what happens is the system version is what pops up on the launch bar. Your edited .desktop won't have the running indicator, the system version will.